# What POS is "welcome" in "welcome to x"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the phrases:

> "welcome home"
>
> "welcome to Jurassic Park"

I always assumed "welcome" was a verb here, and the structure was a shortened form of:

> "(I) welcome (you) home"
>
> "(we) welcome (you all) to Jurassic Park"

In learning Spanish, I started trying to conjugate "bienvenido" like a verb but it turns out it's ONLY an adjective. So in Spanish, the phrases are:

> "(you are) welcome home"
>
> "(you all are) welcome to Jurassic Park"

If I think of these sentences in English, I believe they use "welcome" correctly but the structure seems odd to me.

So in English, in these phrases, what is "welcome" short for and/or what POS is "welcome"? I tried thinking of a definitive example sentence but nothing's coming to mind.

Edit: Maybe "welcome, everyone" shows it's an adj?

Comment: It's often a standalone **interjection**. How this usage arose is another matter.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That kinda makes sense but is it still considered standalone when it has words after it?

Comment: What difference does it make?  It could be "(you are) welcome home" or "(I) welcome (you) home", but the meaning's pretty much the same.  There are more important things to worry about.

Comment: I gave an example where it does matter, but sure, that wasn't in English. And maybe it doesn't matter in English, but I can't verify that for myself, since I'm not an expert on English. We don't know what we don't know. Also, it seems languages have at least a few shortened phrases that now seem unintuitive, and I thought this might be one of them, or otherwise have some history. Anyway, even your dismissive comment gives me some information, suggesting that none of those things are true here.

Comment: If forced to delve further but allowed to give my own take on multi-word expressions, I'd just say I regard 'Welcome home/back' / 'Welcome to X' / even 'made Y very welcome' as idioms, fixed expressions in these cases stretching the grammar involved. There are usages obviously classifiable as noun ('Their welcome was really warm') / verb ('Welcome him as an old friend') / adjective ('It was a welcome respite').

Comment: A year later, I'm now learning German. I came upon "wilkommen" and had the same confusion all over again. Revisiting the options, I agree with @EdwinAshworth's first comment that it makes the most sense as an interjection / fixed phrase.